# Proof of Separation Lemma by Raymond Smullyan in Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems

Tags: logic, incompleteness

In Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems book, Smullyan presents a proof of the Separation Lemma for sets.
Let be S a system, where all formulas of $\Omega_4$ and $\Omega_5$ (axiom schemes of (R)) are provable in S. Let A and B any sets. He wants to show that B-A is separable from A-B by the formula:
$$\forall y(A(x,y)\supset (\exists z\leq y) B(x,z))$$
where: the formula A(x,y) enumerates the set A, and the formula B(x,y) enumerates the set B.

Part of the proof (and my question):

1. Suppose $n\in B-A$. Then $n\in B.$ So, for some k, the sentence $B(\overline n, \overline k)$ is provable.
   Also $n \notin A$, and so for for every $m\leq k$, the sentence $A(\overline n, \overline m)$ is refutable, and, by $\Omega_4$, the sentence $(\forall y\leq \overline k)\sim A(\overline n, y)$ and the open formula $y\leq \overline k \supset \sim A(\overline n, y)$ are provable.
   By using $\Omega_5$, $ A(\overline n, y) \supset \overline k\leq y$ is provable.
   Then, since $B(\overline n, \overline k)$ is provable, then  $A(\overline n, y) \supset ((\overline k\leq y)\land B(\overline n, \overline k))$ is provable.
   My question is about this last statement.
   I think if $A\supset B$ and C are provable, it's not correct to deduce that  $A\supset (B \land C)$ is provable.
   Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think that? (It is indeed valid to deduce the provability of $A\supset (B\wedge C)$ from the provability of $A\supset B$ and $C$.)

Comment: I don't know how to deduce. Can you explain to me?

Comment: Let's start simpler. Do you see how to deduce $X\supset Y$ from $Y$? (The second step will be to deduce $X\supset (Y\wedge Z)$ from $X\supset Y$ and $X\supset Z$, so this is really one half of the problem.) It might also make things easier to get rid of implication by rewriting everything in terms of $\wedge$, $\vee$, and $\neg$ (or $\sim$ depending on what notation your text uses for negation) - remember that $X\supset Y$ is the same as $Y\vee\neg X$.

Comment: What inference rules are you using? Not "modus ponens" and generalization only?

Comment: Any set of inference rules satisfying the completeness theorem will do. I don't know the system you're presented with, but it will be capable of yielding each of these deductions. (For example, if "$\vee$" is included as a primitive logical operation in your system, you probably have a pair of "$\vee$-introduction" rules which let you deduce $X\vee Y$ and $Y\vee X$ respectively from $Y$ for every $X,Y$.)

Comment: See Mendelson's textbook for a proof system using only $\lnot$ and $\to$ as connectives and MP and Gen as inference rule, like Smullyan's one, for the derivation of e.g. $A \to (B \to (A \land B))$.

Comment: I'll add that just because Smullyan uses a Hilbert system as the official deductive system doesn't mean you should have to in this verification. Hilbert systems have a simple proof syntax that is convenient for Gödel encoding, but aren't very intuitive to use directly for proofs. It is more convenient to just verify that this is a valid inference by truth tables or natural deduction, and trust that Smullyan's system is complete for propositional logic, so it can prove the inference. (It might be worth verifying this if he doesn't, but do it once and don't let it slow you down after you do.)

Comment: Thank you all, especially Noah. I think I need to study more axiomatic propositional logic. Bye.